# Dihedral angle from Coxeter diagram

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, symmetry, angle, polytopes

The *regular polytopes* are completely described by their [Coxeter diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter%E2%80%93Dynkin_diagram).

Is there a way to compute their [*dihedral angles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_angle) (angle between adjacent facets) from the combinatorial data in the diagram?
Clearly, the dihedral angles are well-defined by the diagram only (after all, I can construct the geometric object from the diagram). 
But I am specifically asking about a not too complicated direct way (a formula maybe) to obtain these angles from the diagram.

[image]

Moreover, I am explicitly looking for an approach that does *not* presuppose the classification of regular polytopes (reflection groups, root systems, etc.).
I want an "algorithm" that only takes in a valid Coxeter diagram, and works with that.

---

**Update 1**

Here is a different way to phrase it. 
If I have $n$ lineary independent unit vectors $v_1,...,v_n\in\Bbb S^{n-1}$, and all I know of them are numbers $m_{ij}\in\Bbb N,i,j\in\{1,...,n\},i\not=j$ so that

$$\langle v_i,v_j\rangle = \cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{m_{ij}}\Big),$$

then how to find the angle between $v_n$ and the hyperplane spanned by $v_1,...,v_{n-1}$. The dihedral angle is twice that angle.

---

**Update 2**

Let $\bar v_1,...,\bar v_{n-1}\in\Bbb R^n$ be the dual basis of $v_1,...,v_{n-1}$ in the span of these vectors.

Let $M=(v_1,...,v_{n-1})\in\Bbb R^{n\times (n-1)}$ is the matrix with the $v_i$ as columns, and equivalently, $\bar M\in\Bbb R^{n\times(n-1)}$ the matrix with the $\bar v_i$ as columns. Then

$$\cos \angle (\mathrm{span}(v_1,...,v_{n-1}),v_n)=\|M \bar M^\top\! v_n\|.$$

I think it should even be possible to show that this is the same as $\langle v_n,\bar v_{n-1}\rangle/\|\bar v_{n-1}\|$.
Can any of this be nicely expressed using only the $m_{ij}$?

Comment: For regular polytopes, you can read the Schlafli symbol from a Coxeter diagram. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2748840/409) gives a formula that converts a polyhedron's $\{p,q\}$ symbol to a dihedral angle; [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2750226/409) gives a corresponding formula for a polytope's $\{p,q,r\}$ symbol. There are only three (convex) regular figures in five or more dimensions; their dihedral angles aren't too difficult to determine individually, but I haven't checked if there's a unified formula for them.

Comment: @Blue Thank you for these links. I will definitely look into this. To your last sentence: I am explicitly looking for an approach that does *not* presuppose the classification of the regular polytopes. I will edit this into the question.

Comment: I don't think you can get away from the classification of the regular polytopes so easily. You need a 'marked up' Coxeter diagram to be able to disambiguate between dual polyhedra, so the raw diagram isn't enough — but then, a priori, there's no reason to expect any particular marked diagram to be regular, and uniform polyhedra may have multiple dihedral angles. So somewhere along this process you're either going to need to assume the classification of the regular polytopes, or you'll be deriving it...

Comment: @Steven There is *a lot* one can know without using the classification. If one defines regular as *flag-transitive* (actually, *flag-regular*), then one can deduce that the symmetry group of a regular polytope $P$ is a reflection group. Furthermore, all facets are regular as well, and you can obtain their symmetry group by dropping one of the generating mirrors of the reflection group of $P$. In other words, the Coxeter diagram of a face is obtained from the Coxeter diagram of the polytope by dropping one of the nodes. This and a little more I used to bring the problem in the updated form.

Comment: On the other hand, the approach under "Update 2" is probably not restricted to the Coxeter diagrams of regular polytopes. But it is still a well-defined problem and I am courios about any answer to it. :) 
If necessary, I am happy with assuming that the Coxeter diagram is a path with no branches.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the according outline provided [here](https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/explain/dihedral.htm). $-$
Essentially that one comes up with the formula asked for here (and several ones more, including their derivations, as well as providing various explicite numerical values):

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\text{2D:} & \text{@-p-o} & \alpha(1,1')=\arccos\left(1-2\cdot\frac P4\right)\\
\text{3D:} & \text{@-p-o-q-o} & \alpha(2,2')=\arccos\left(1-2\cdot\frac{Q}{4-P}\right)\\
\text{4D:} & \text{@-p-o-q-o-r-o} & \alpha(3,3')=\arccos\left(1-2\cdot\frac{4-P}4\cdot\frac R{4-P-Q}\right)\\
\end{array}$$

where $P=4\cdot\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}p\right)$, $Q=4\cdot\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}q\right)$, and $R=4\cdot\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}r\right)$.

--- rk

Comment: That's very interesting. Is there a pattern to this that extends to higher dimensions?

Comment: Beyond 4D the regulars are quite few: simplices, orthoplexes, and hypercubes only. For those the values can be derived directly: $\alpha_{simplex}=\arccos(1/D)$, $\alpha_{orthoplex}=\arccos(2/D - 1)$, $\alpha_{hypercube}=\pi/2$. - That would be much faster than trying to expand the way of that other page, I guess.

Comment: Sure, but my question was explicitly about *not* using the classification of regular polytopes.